# unobtrusive Javascript, should I use it? what is the best way to manage and organize events? how do I prevent inefficiencies?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, code-organization

I have been struggling with choosing unobtrusive javascript over defining it within the html syntax. I want to convince my self to go the unobtrusive route, but I am having trouble getting past the issues listed below. Can you please help convince me :)

1) When you bind events unobtrusively, there is extra overhead on the client's machine to find that html element, where as when you do stuff, you don't have to iterate the DOM.

2) There is a lag between when events are bound using document.ready() (jquery) and when the page loads. This is more apparent on very large sites.

3) If you bind events (onclick etc) unobtrusively, there is no way of looking at the html code and knowing that there is an event bound to a particular class or id. This can become problematic when updating the markup and not realizing that you may be effecting javascript code. Is there a naming convention when defining css elements which are used to bind javascript events (i have seen ppl use js_className)

4) For a site, there  are different pieces of javascript for different pages. For example Header.html contains a nav which triggers javascript events on all pages, where as homepage.html and searchPage.html contains elements that trigger javascript on their respective pages

sudo code example:

header.html

```
<script src="../myJS.js"></script>
<div>Header</div>
<ul>
<li>nav1</li><li>nav2</li>
</ul>
```

homepage.html

```
<@include header.html>
<div class="homepageDiv">some stuff</div>
```

searchpage.html

```
<@include header.html>
<div class="searchpageDiv">some other stuff</div>
```

myJS.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("ul.li").bind("click",doSomething());
$(".homePageDiv").bind("click",doSomethingElse());
$(".searchPageDiv").bind("click",doSomethingSearchy());
});
```

In this case when you are on the searchPage it will still try to look for the "homepageDiv" which does not exist and fail. This will not effect the functionality but thats an additional unnecessary traversal. I could break this up into seperate javascript files, but then the browser has to download multiple files, and I can't just serve one file and have it cached for all pages.

What is the best way to use unobtrusive javascript so that I could easily maintain a ( pretty script heavy) website, so another developer is aware of scripts being bound to html elements when they are modifying my code. And serve the code so that the client's browser is not looking for elements which do not exist on a particular page (but may exist on others).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are confused. Unobtrusive JavaScript is not just about defining event handlers in a program. It's a set of rules for writing JavaScript such that the script doesn't affect the functionality of other JavaScript on the same page. JavaScript is a dynamic language. Anyone can make changes to anything. Thus if two separate scripts on the same page both define a global variable `add` as follows, the last one to define it will *win* and affect the functionality of the first script.

```
// script 1
var add = function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
};

// script 2
add = 5;

//script 1 again
add(2, 3); // error - add is a number, not a function
```

Now, to answer your question directly:

1. The extra overhead to find an element in JavaScript and attach an event listener to it is not a lot. You can use the new DOM method `document.querySelector` to find an element quickly and attach an event listener to it (it takes less than 1 ms to find the element).
2. If you want to attach your event listeners quickly, don't do it when your document content loads. Attach your event listeners at the end of the body section or directly after the part of your HTML code to which you wish to attach the event listener.
3. I don't see how altering the markup could affect the JavaScript in any manner. If you try to attach an event listener to an element that doesn't exist in JavaScript, it will silently fail or throw an exception. Either way, it really won't affect the functionality of the rest of the page. In addition, a HTML designer really doesn't need to know about the events attached any element. HTML is only supposed to be used for semantic markup; CSS is used for styling; and JavaScript is used for behavior. Don't mix up the three.
4. God has given us free will. Use it. JavaScript supports conditional execution. There are `if` statements. See if `homePageDiv` exists and only then attach an event listener to it.

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul.li").bind("click",doSomething());
    if (document.querySelector(".homePageDiv")) {
        $(".homePageDiv").bind("click",doSomethingElse());
    } else {
        $(".searchPageDiv").bind("click",doSomethingSearchy());
    }
});
```

Your question had very little to do with unobtrusive JavaScript. It showed a lack of research and understanding. Thus, I'm down voting it. Sorry.

Comment: Unfortunately i think my main question is being missed.
I do understand unobtrusive javascript and my questions stem from one of its main principles, the seperation of the functional and presentation layers (hence all the reference to binding events)
I will try and re work my question so its a little clearer.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just because `jQuery.ready()` executes does not mean that the page is visible to the end user. This is a behaviour defined by browsers and these days there are really 2 events to take into consideration here as mootools puts it `DomReady` vs `Load`. When jQuery executes the `ready` method it's talking about the dom loading loaded however this doesn't mean the page is ready to be viewed by the user, external elements which as pictures and even style sheets etc may still be loading.

Any binding you do, even extremely inefficient ones will bind a lot faster than all the external resources being loaded by the browser so IMHO user should experience no difference between the page being displayed and functionality being made available.

As for finding binding on elements in your DOM. You are really just fearing that things will get lost. This has not really been my actual experience, more often than not in your JS you can check what page you are on and only add javascript for that page (as Aadit mentioned above). After that a quick find operation in your editor should help you find anything if stuff gets lost.

Keep in mind that under true MVC the functionality has to be separate from the presentation layer. This is exactly what OO javascript or unobtrusive javascript is about. You should be able to change your DOM without breaking the functionality of the page. Yes, if you change the css class and or element id on which you bind your JS will break, however the user will have no idea of this and the page will at least appear to work. However if this is a big concern you can use OO-Javascript and put `div`'s or `span`'s as placeholders in your dom and use these as markers to insert functionality or tell you that it exists, you can even use html comments. However, in my experience you know the behavior of your site and hence will always know that there is some JS there.

While I understand most of your concerns about useless traversals, I do think you are nickle and dime'ing it at this point if you are worried about 1 additional traversal. *Previous to IE8 it used to be the case that traversing with the tag name and id was a lot faster than my selector but this is no longer true infact browsers have evolved to be much faster when using just the selectors*:

- `$("a#myLink")` - slowest.
- `$("a.myLink")` - faster.
- `$("#Link")` - fastest.
- `$(".myLink")` - fastest.

In the link below you can see that as many as 34 thousand operations per second are being performed so I doubt speed is an issue.

You can use firebug to test the speed of each in the case of a very large dom.

In Summary:

a) Don't worry about losing js code there is always `ctrl+f`

b) There is no lag because dom ready does not mean the page is visible to start with.

**Update**
Fixed order of speed in operations based on the tests results from [here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-speed-tests)
However keep in mind that performances of IE < 8 are really had if you don't specify the container (this used to be the rule, now it seems to be the exception to the rule).

Comment: Your explanation of the speed of selectors is *very* wrong, and is almost the opposite of what's true.

Comment: You're right [Test samples using jquery](http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-speed-tests) my testing was done with Prototype library and at least through FB the results were faster... I'll update the answer, still, it only goes to show that there is no reason to worry above speed.

Comment: Unfortunately people are still using IE7 and below
but in general what u said makes sense. I came across an implementation of namespaces in javascript which i think might be a good way to manage javascript at a page level.